# Vyper: compatible to write/deploy Ethereum classic smart-contract with python?

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, vyper, ethereumclassic

Since [Python Serpent Compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent) is [considered outdated and not secure by Vitalik](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/886400133667201024) (also confirmed by [this  audit](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_PqXuAkvgUAOG3jbBvaUvqN6W90eJ3N4IdTLNMRAijo/edit#heading=h.jz3nh6kdhwt2) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/why-did-serpent-die)), it is more recommended to write/deploy Ethereum [smart-contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) from python with [Vyper compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper).

It is sure that [Vyper](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper) works on the [Ethereum decentralized platform](https://www.ethereum.org/), but I would to know if [Vyper](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper) is also compatible to deploy [smart contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) on the [Ethereum Classic decentralized platform](https://ethereumclassic.github.io/) ?

If yes, how to setup [Vyper](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper) for this use case ?

If no, what is the new python supported compiler to deploy [smart contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) on [Ethereum Classic](https://ethereumclassic.github.io/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, both ETC and ETH use EVM for their code, and neither have diverged in their implementation of the EVM. This means that no extra setup should be necessary to get Vyper code running on ETC instead of ETH.